# Drawing Rectangle images-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

In my first LibGdx Project,I want to draw some rectangles.

I am not looking for shape rendering purpose.I am aiming to implement a function like what fillRect() in j2me do.I have to draw filled rectangles and need to manipulate it(changing size,rotating.. etc).
When I google about it, always getting shapeRenderer related things only.

Please mention how can I  draw and manipulate my own images.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. How does ShapeRenderer not match what you want?

Comment: I am looking for simple drawing operations..rectangle,circle etc

Comment: That's what ShapeRenderer does.

Comment: @Niranjana you can create texture with pixmap, after that with texture you can create Sprite or scene2d element Image. Can resize and rotate according to your  requirement.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @AbhishekAryanThank you!Pixmap worked well for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw Rectangle by using Pixmap.

```
Texture texture=getPixmapTexture(Color.WHITE);

Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture); //Used for drawing 2D sprites.
//or
Image image=new Image(texture);  //2D scene graph node.

public static Texture getPixmapTexture(Color color){
    return new Texture(PixmapBuilder.getPixmapRectangle(1, 1, color));
}     

public static Pixmap getPixmapRectangle(int width, int height, Color color){
       Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
       pixmap.setColor(color);
       pixmap.fillRectangle(0,0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());
       return pixmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Abhishek is correct.

However, if you have just started game developement with LibGDX, I would check whether you need at all to perform such operation (draw a rectangle).
In libGDX you can use Scene2D which allow you to create a Stage, Actors and direct them on your stage.
So instead of drawing a rectangle, you create an actor, such as an image, to which you can associate a texture, a button or a TextBox and place it on your screen.
Scene2D allows you to then use things like Action or rotation, scaling..
There are some good visual demos about that on [Libgdx.info](https://libgdx.info/)

I am mentioning this because moving to Scene2D later may be more complicated than if you make that decision early on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!In some demo game codes,I have seen using stage and related things in menu only.So I did the same.Is stage useful in game play screen also?

Comment: yes, I give you an example: my game wordfiesta was created entirely with Scene2D: (Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordfiesta.free_version) (iOS https://itunes.apple.com/bj/app/word-fiesta-free-version/id1050452690?mt=8)

Comment: I know a lot of years have passed since 2017 but that link now gets to a 18+ site